# How to load plain text in to div from another page

Tags: ajax, jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to load content from another page div into another page div.

What i've got:

JQUERY:

```
$('#news_date-1').load('test.php .news_date-1');
```

TEST.PHP

```
<div class="news_date-1">20-11-2009</div>
```

Destination.html

```
 <div id="news_date-1"></div>
```

The result i get =

```
<div id="news_date-1"><div class="news_date-1">20-11-2009</div></div>
```

The result i want =

```
<div id="news_date-1">20-11-2009</div>
```

Can anybody help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try calling [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) on it in the callback.

```
$('#news_date-1').load('test.php .news_date-1', function () {
    $(this) //will refer to #news_date-1
        .find('.news_date-1') //find the inserted div inside
        .contents() //find all its contents
        .unwrap(); //unwrap the contents, thus removing the unneeded div
});
```

This is not the most beautiful solution, because `.load()` already inserts it into the DOM, and then you tamper with the DOM again, which should be minimized.

Another way I see is using `$.get()` instead:

```
$.get('test.php', function(receivedHtml) {
    //getting only the parts we need
    var neededHtml = $(receivedHtml).find('.news_date-1').html();
    //adding it to DOM
    $('#news_date-1').append(neededHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.get('test.php', function(data) {
    $('#news_date-1').append($(data).find('.news_date-1'));
});
```